# Android webview not displaying/parsing html tags

Tags: android, webview

I have a Webview which depending on what the user clicks in an activity displays different html with tags, however the tags are not being parsed (ie the webview just displays the raw text) or doesnt display anything at all.

The webview is set with:

```
((WebView)routeInfoMenu.findViewById(R.id.routeInfo_titleDesc)).loadData(routeDesc, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

the "outeDesc" contents for example:

```
<p>This is some example text, this is <b>BOLD</b></p>
```

The xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rdm_routeInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rdm_routeInfoWhite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:clickable="true" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/routeInfo_titleText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/route_name"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="19sp"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/routeInfo_titleDesc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/routeInfo_titleText"
                        android:text="@string/route_desc"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:maxLines="500"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `loadDataWithBaseURL()` instead of `loadData()`. Example:

```
((WebView)routeInfoMenu.findViewById(R.id.routeInfo_titleDesc)).loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```